# How can I create a video (from RGB and PCM) programatically with GStreamer?

Tags: c++, video, audio, record, gstreamer

My application displays video and audio and I want to add a recording feature.

I've considered FFmpeg, but I have to compile my application with VS so I can't use it. So I'm trying to do it with GStreamer, but I'm not finding any example or guide on how to create a video. Any help?

(I can also consider using any other alternatives, but they must be cross-platform).

Answer (score 0):

[Application Development Manual](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/index.html) explains very well how to use gstreamer from your code. Try to read it first.

Than you can experiment with `gst-launch` tool, build pipeline and execute it from your application using [gst-parse-launch](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch) function.

You can expose more details of your problem if you want more helpful answer.